# Does anyone know what kind of plant this is?

Tags: identification, flowers

all! I need some help. I overwatered a friend's plant and need to replace it. Does anyone know what kind of plant this is? Any help would be super appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a Purple Heart Tradescantia that has fallen on hard times. In your image we can see some old leaves that are clasping the stem, a feature of the trandescantia, plus note the way that the plant compartmentalizes its water resources by shutting off damage at particular nodes. Here is an image from another site that shows the same compartmentalization - https://getbusygardening.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/wandering-jew-purple-heart.jpg. Does this picture remind you of what the plant looked like?

You could still save the plant by taking some cuttings (pieces of healthy stem) from what is left and putting them in water, then as soon as the roots start to appear (it will root very easily) move to soil in a pot. I'm sure your friend will appreciate the effort to restore the original plant!